# What's a Pythonic way to add a list (or other iterator) of key/value pairs to a dict?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

To construct a dict using values transformed from a list, set, generator or dict, I use a dict comprehension.

```
d = { r['name']:r for r in responses }
```

Here `responses` is a dict, I could also be using a list, for example:

```
d = { extract_the_key(r):extract_the_value for r in responses }
```

Now suppose that I already have the dict. How do I add the same key-value pairs to my dict.

Of course, I could do:

```
for r in responses:
    d[extract_the_key(r)] = extract_the_value(r)
```

But this seems less Pythonic and plain uglier. Is there an idiomatic way of doing this?

Note that I might 'already have' the dict because I have already set some values in it. But I might equally already have it, because it is a `defaultdict` or some other extension from `dict`. This means that I can't just create a new dict using the new values, and then take the union of the two in some 'comprehension-style' way.

Comment: How about `dict.update(sequence_of_pairs)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `update` method of dictionaries, e.g.

```
d.update((extract_the_key(r), extract_the_value(r)) for r in responses)
```